# How to redirect to a route without using react-router

Tags: reactjs

I have a component in a public page (search component) that should render a link to a react route.

How can I solve this ?
Just using  doesn't work very well.

Comment: maybe `window.location`

Comment: hey @AjjHsh, perhaps show us some code so we can better assist you

Answer (score 0):

If the page exists outside of the react-router , you will probably just need to use a url.

Comment: but when I use <a href... the redirect doesn't work